# intellij idea scala "" autocompletion turn-off

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

When I start to type `"`, scala plugin automatically adds the "closing" quotation marks. The same goes for `(` etc.

How do I turn of this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings -> Editor -> Smart Keys -> 
       uncheck `"Insert pair bracket"` and `"Insert pair quote"`

They are checked by default